# How to properly write a function that search for the data in firebase database in react?

Tags: reactjs

I have firebase database and I am using crud functionalities in my app. I want to have a component that has search input and where user would be able to search by the hotel title. I have added input button and I am able to fetch all the data, but filter is not working :(
Any idea why?
Below, you can see my function:

```
  const SearchHotel=(e: { preventDefault: () => void; })=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    setHotel(hotel.filter((hotel: { Title: string; })=>
    hotel.Title.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
    ));
  };
```

Basically, I get error on ,,filter'', so I guess here is the problem. Maybe somone has any good advise on hoe to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

To filter immediately previous state you should use prevState argument in function passed to setState.

```
setHotel(prevState => prevState.filter((hotel: { Title: string; }) =>
    hotel.Title.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
));
```

And you should save the original array and filtered array save to other state. If you didn't save them, you will  lost original array and will not be able to show user all hotels when he delete his input